# Обход иерархии групп

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Есть иерархия групп, в которой у групп являющихся корнем (вершиной) может быть несколько прямых потомков, у этих потомков могут быть тоже несколько прямых потомков и так далее.
Программно это реализовано в виде объекта класса, содержащего ссылку на объект родитель и коллекцию содержащею ссылки на своих прямых потомков:

```
 public class Groupu
{
    
    public int IdGroup { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
           
    [DisplayName("Подчиняется")]
    public virtual Groupu GroupParents { get; set; }
   
    public virtual ICollection<Groupu> ChildGroups { get; set; }

}
```

Нужно узнать всех потомков какой-либо группы (объекта) на всю глубину, т.е. до самого низа.
Чисто теоретически это обход графа в глубину, вроде как? Если нет, то исправьте меня.

Но есть ещё не понятные моменты, например при поиске в глубину у нас должно быть условия выхода - нахождение заданного объекта, в данной задаче у нас нет такого объекта, а нам нужно получить весь список его потомков (прямых и не прямых).

Я попытался реализовать алгоритм обхода графа в ширину, но у меня получилось, что я обхожу только прямых потомков потомков текущего объекта, а глубже уже не получается:

```
public List<Groupu> GetAllChildGroupsBFS(List<Groupu> groupChild, Groupu groupStart)
        {
            // groupChild - список потомков
            // groupStart - начальный потомок
            // t - пункт назначения, его нет

            // Список всех посещенных потомков
            List<Groupu> childGroupus = new List<Groupu>();

            // инициализируем очередь
            Queue<Groupu> queueGroupu = new Queue<Groupu>();
            // добавляем groupStart в очередь
            queueGroupu.Enqueue(groupStart);
            // помечаем groupStart как посещенную вершину во избежание повторного добавления в очередь
            groupStart.Visited = true;

            while (queueGroupu.Count > 0)
            {
                // удаляем первый (верхний) элемент из очереди
                Groupu gr = queueGroupu.Dequeue();
                //Добавляем посещенную вершину в список потомков
                childGroupus.Add(gr);
                // groupChild - потомки
                foreach (Groupu childgr in groupChild)
                {
                    // если сосед не посещался
                    if (!childgr.Visited)
                    {
                        // добавляем его в очередь
                        queueGroupu.Enqueue(childgr);
                        // помечаем вершину как посещенную
                        childgr.Visited = true;
                        //Добавляем посещенную вершину в список потомков
                        childGroupus.Add(childgr);

                        //Условие выхода
                    }
                }
            }
            // Возвращение списка потомков
            return childGroupus;
        }
```

Ещё попробовал реализовать обход графа в глубину, но тут у меня тоже получается обойти только прямых потомков моих потомков:

```
public bool GetAllChildGroupsDFS(List<Groupu> groupChild, Groupu group)
        {
            // groupChild - список потомков
            // group - посещенный потомок
            // t - пункт назначения, его нет

            // Список всех посещенных потомков
            List<Groupu> childGroupus = new List<Groupu>();

            // это общие случаи
            // либо достигли пункта назначения, либо уже посещали узел
            if (group.Visited) return false;

            // помечаем узел как посещенный
            group.Visited = true;
            //Добавляем посещенную группу в список потомков
            childGroupus.Add(group);

            // исследуем всех соседей (ближайшие потомки группы) group
            foreach (Groupu childGr in groupChild)
            {
                // если сосед не посещался
                if (!childGr.Visited)
                {
                    // двигаемся по пути и проверяем, не достигли ли мы пункта назначения
                    bool reached = GetAllChildGroupsDFS(groupChild, childGr);
                    // возвращаем true, если достигли
                    if (reached) return true;
                }
            }
            // Если прошли весь путь, а условие поиска не выполнилось
            return false;
        }
```

Помогите с реализацией пожалуйста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, это обход дерева.

Какой именно - от вида обхода зависит порядок вывода. [Вот для бинарных деревьев](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0) - для произвольного количества деток всё будет похоже

При обходе в глубину выводятся ветки до самого низа, потом подъём к корню и т.д.

При обходе в ширину вывод будет происходить по уровням - все узлы первого уровня, потом все узлы второго и т.д.

Условие остановки - нечего больше обходить.

```
public List<Groupu> GetAllChildGroupsBFS(List<Groupu> groupChild, Groupu groupStart)
        {
            // groupChild - список потомков
            // groupStart - начальный потомок

            // Список всех посещенных потомков
            List<Groupu> childGroupus = new List<Groupu>();

            // инициализируем очередь
            Queue<Groupu> queueGroupu = new Queue<Groupu>();
            // добавляем groupStart в очередь
            queueGroupu.Enqueue(groupStart);
            while (queueGroupu.Count > 0)
            {
                // удаляем первый (верхний) элемент из очереди
                Groupu gr = queueGroupu.Dequeue();
                //Добавляем посещенную вершину в список потомков
                childGroupus.Add(gr);
                // groupChild - потомки
                foreach (Groupu childgr in gr.ПРЯМЫЕ_ПОТОМКИ)
                {
                        // добавляем его в очередь
                        queueGroupu.Enqueue(childgr);
                }
            }
            // Возвращение списка потомков
            return childGroupus;
        }
```

Comment: У меня вариант сложнее, в бинарном дереве мы рекурсивно вызываем функцию от правого потомка и левого потомка, но у меня таких потомков список, я попытался по аналогии, но что-то у меня не очень получилось. Свои варианты я добавил в ответ

Comment: Что-то вы усложняете. Для дерева не нужно проверять и вообще заводить visited. Я не очень понял - дети у вас в `InverseGroupParents`? В любом случае  foreach (Groupu childgr in **groupChild**) неверно.Нужно обходить прямых потомков gr, а не узла из заголовка функции.

Comment: Да, дети в ``InverseGroupParents```. Переименовал сейчас ```InverseGroupParents``` в ```ChildGroups```. И в этом списке может быть не 2, а 3  и более, поэтому я в цикле и перебирал каждого, так мне показалось будет верным

Comment: Да, в цикле перебираем всех детей, но детей того узла, с которым работаем, а не изначального. Вы увидели у меня в коде  ` foreach (Groupu childgr in gr.ПРЯМЫЕ_ПОТОМКИ)`?

Comment: Да, буду пробовать

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось